# Create new document using plugin indesign CC2015 SDK

Tags: sdk, adobe-indesign

I am new to indesign SDK programming. Learning SDK basics to develop a plugin. I got some idea about SDK plugin development and to build, release.

Now,I would like to know how to create the new indesign document when the user clicks on the plugin menu item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Utils<IDocumentCommands>()->CreateNewCommand(kFullUI)` to get `ICommand` interface to create a new document. You can get `INewDocCmdData` interface on `ICommand` to configure the parameters to set for the document. Header files for these interfaces can give you more documentation on what you can do with these interfaces.
If you are looking for how menu item actions are handled, you might want to look at `IActionComponent`.